# How to print values computed from variables in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, variables

I have a `FormGroup`in a component like:

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    $key: new FormControl(null),
    from: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    to: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    quantity: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')]),
    price: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')]),
    ticker: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
```

And in the html, I have the Input elements to accept the inputs for each of the five form-controls.

I'm just facing some trouble in outputting Amount to the html:

```
<p>Amount: {{ form.controls['quantity'] * form.controls['price']}}</p>
```

I'm getting errors:

`The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`

`The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`

Can someone help me to understand whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the variables to numbers.

Try this:

```
<p>Amount: {{ +form.controls['quantity'] * +form.controls['price']}}</p>
```

Or change type of your input to number:

```
<input type="number" formControlName="quantity">
<input type="number" formControlName="price">
```

And change your form:

```
quantity: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
price: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bazhan, but actually this below modification gave the expected output:

```
<p>Amount: {{ form.value.quantity * form.value['price']}}</p>
```

I should have accessed the `value` field instead of the `controls` field.